# How to find the no of years in which population of both.the cities become equal?

Tags: propositional-calculus

City A' s population is $96000$ and it is decreasing by $800$ per year and city B' s population is $68000$ which is increasing by $1200$ per year. After how many years population of both the city becomes equal? If I have to solve this question in less than 1 minute what I have to do?

Comment: If your numbers are accurate, then the population of the cities will never become equal. 'A' starts with fewer people and decreases, while 'B' starts with more and increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$$96000-800x=y$$$$68000+1200x=y$$

Now solve for $$x=?,y=?$$

In **x** years, they will both have **y** people

Comment: The question (as it is currently written) says $9600$ not $96000$.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks, I didn't see that.

Comment: And using $9600$, there is no (positive) solution for $x$.

Comment: @Deepak I think the OP mistook 96000 for 9600

Comment: I think so too, but it's up to the OP to clarify.

Comment: OK, OP has clarified, your answer can be reverted back to its original form.

Comment: Sorry it was mistook as 9600 instead of 96000.

Comment: @AayushMukharji Ok, I edited the answer. If you find the value of $x$ and $y$ then that will be your answer

Comment: Thanks for it. With your guidance I solved it in 14 years both the cities will be at the population of 84,800.

Answer (score 2):

The simple approach is to note that they start $28000$ apart and the difference decreases by $2000$ per year.  You just have to divide $\frac {28}2=14$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks I needed the most quick solution thanks for helping me .

Answer (score 0):

Create two equations for the population per year for City A and City B. Use a variable like $n$ for the year and then set these two equation equal to each other (in other words same population) and solve for $n$.